# Realm and the inclusion of System.Diagnostics.Debug nuget package

Tags: realm, upgrade

I'm just about to upgrade to v0.88.1 of Realm dotnet. I noticed that it has started using the .NET standard packages.

I also noticed that one of the packages is System.Diagnostics.Debug.4.0.11

Is this intentional. Will it be ignored in a release build? IS there anything I should be concerned about here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: nothing to worry about.

The assemblies brought in are just reference assemblies (already part of mscorlib) and will not be duplicated in the final application bundle. If you have enabled linking, unused parts of mscorlib (such as `System.Diagnostics.Debug`) will be linked away during build. Otherwise, they will be included, but will be ignored, as nothing is using them.

As a side note, those packages are included due to the dependency on [Remotion.Linq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Remotion.Linq/).